On Inertial Reference Frames
I know this question has been asked multiple times, even after months of effort, I am not able to find a convincing explanation.
An inertial reference frame is defined as a frame of reference in which a body which is experiencing no net force (Gravitation, Electromagnetic, Strong, Weak Nuclear Forces) is observed to move at constant velocity.
Now my questions are why is Earth an approximate inertial reference frame for bodies on its surface? I do not find the explanation "Coriolis Force and Centrifugal forces have negligible effect over short distances " A convincing explanation. Because when you are measuring a pseudo force, you need to measure the acceleration of the non inertial reference frame with respect to the inertial reference frame. But we do not know of an inertial reference frame, so how can we measure the Coriolis Force, or any other psuedoforces  and call them negligible?
Further suppose a satellite is being sent from here to Mars, Thus when it escapes earth's atmosphere, our "approximate inertial reference frame" should not work, and so What is the frame of reference is used for this scenario. Is the Sun used as an approximate inertial reference frame? If yes then what justifies it? Why are we able to predict the orbits of planets while sitting in a non inertial reference frame?
This might seem like a lot of questions, but most of the time the answers to my query is that an inertial reference frame is one which is not accelerating (Which is a meaningless statements as it violates the fact that there is no privileged observer in space and it is not accelerating to which frame?) I hope I could get a better explanation.


Because when you are measuring a pseudo force, you need to measure the acceleration of the non inertial reference frame with respect to the inertial reference frame.

Actually, you don't need a real inertial reference frame to measure with respect to.  To tell if a reference frame is inertial or not, you do an experiment which has some predictable results in an inertial frame and see how far it deviates from those results.  If it doesn't measurably deviate, you can treat it as inertial.  An example experiment might be a Coriolis Carousel.  In this experiment you pass a ball to someone straight across from you.  If you are in an inertial frame, it will go directly towards them in your reference frame (in a straight line).  If you are in a rotating frame, it will curve in your reference frame due to the Coriolis effect.  Now yes, the standard way of thinking is "an outside inertial observer will see the ball move in a straight line," but we don't need someone to observe that.  All we need to do is observe that, in our reference frame, the ball curves in a way that would not be expected if the frame was indeed inertial.

Thus when it escapes earth's atmosphere, our "approximate inertial reference frame" should not work...

Actually, it will work.  A non-inertial reference frame is still consistent.  The satellite will continue to obey the laws of motion in that reference frame.
Now what will happen is that eventually it starts to be less and less useful to do computations in a Earth Fixed reference frame (a non-inertial reference frame which rotates at just the right rate to keep a point on the surface of the earth at the same coordinate while the Earth spins).  It doesn't give you a wrong result. It just becomes more obnoxious.
Typically for interplanetary missions we do indeed use a reference system based on the sun.  Well... almost.  It turns out that that reference system is a bit non-inertial itself.  It's more effective to make the reference system based on the barycenter of the solar system, that is its center of mass.  That's mostly dominated by the mass of the sun, but it turns out Jupiter is big enough to meaningfully tug the barycenter abut 100 million meters outside of the sun's volume.
It's not that this is the only system that works.  We choose it because it makes our mathematics easier.  It's easier to calculate in inertial coordinate systems.
Now your question about "approximately inertial reference frames" depends on how well you can measure.  "Approximate" means it's not the right answer, but it's close enough to accomplish what you need to accomplish.  For every day life on the surface of the planet, we can say Earth Fixed is "approximately inertial."  You have to work hard to detect the non-inertial aspects of it (such as by setting up a copy of Foucault's Pendulum)
So how far does this go?  How close to inertial can we get?  The answer is a lesson in the astonishing discipline of metrology.  Metrology studies measurement and calibration, and it is the metrologists that care most about just how inertial a frame can be.
The metrologists do care about the motion and acceleration of frames.  So a reference system centered on the barycenter of the solar system is more inertial than one centered on the Earth (which is revolving around the barycenter).  But what turns out to be really important is the orientation and how it rotates.  Rotation is what leads to the really interesting non-inertial effects, like the Coriolis effect or Euler accelerations.
So we recognize that the Earth is rotating.  So a Earth Fixed frame is non-inertial.  We could imagine an inertial frame, but what would it look like?  The first guess is to use the stars.  And, indeed, metrologists did so.  This culminated in the FK5 reference frame which was astonishingly inertial (although still approximate).  Us normal humans would never notice it drifting off of inertial.
But we got better and better at measuring, and it turns out that stars move in the night sky.  They're slow, but they truly move (as one should expect, really.  There's no reason they shouldn't have some motion with respect to us).  And FK5 started getting tricky.
So we created an even more inertial system.  We created the International Celestial Reference System(ICRS).  This was based on the assumption that very far off objects don't move very much angularly.  Any movement gets divided out by the astonishing distance to those objects, so the angular movement is very slight.  We picked 212 far off objects ("extragalactic" was the starting point... they looked for objects that are far off in an extragalactic sense), and built a frame that assumes they, on average, define an inertial coordinate system.
And even that isn't truly inertial.  But to dig deeper we're really going to have to start talking about general relativity and measurement errors and all sorts of things we usually don't have to think about.

OK, take that definition - "An inertial reference frame is defined as a frame of reference in which a body which is experiencing no net force (Gravitation, Electromagnetic, Strong, Weak Nuclear Forces) is observed to move at constant velocity." and apply it. Imagine we are sat in our lab on Earth, and we turn off  the gravity from the Earth, sun, moon, and other bodies. What will the subsequent motion be, observed in the reference frame fixed to the lab?
Objects will drift off tangentially to the surface of the Earth in the direction of rotation. There will be an additional drift tangential to the Earth's orbit around the sun. But it will not be hugely dramatic. Your upwards velocity at time $t$ after the switch-off would be approximately $\omega^2 Rt$, where $\omega$ is one revolution per day, or $2\pi/86400$ s$^{-1}$, and $R$ is 6371 km. That's about $0.033 t$ ms$^{-1}$. After about a minute you would be moving at $2$ ms$^{-1}$.
The rotation around the sun is even slower - one rotation per year, although obviously the radius of the Earth's orbit is much bigger. The net result is that the contribution from the Earth's orbit around the sun is even smaller.
Because a rotation of one turn per day, or one turn per year, is pretty small, then so long as you are within the confines of your lab, it's pretty inertial.
If you want to take a trip to Mars, then we would normally use heliocentric coordinates for doing the calculations, rather than ones based on our lab back on Earth. Of course, the sun isn't quite inertial either, given that it is orbiting the galactic centre. But if you turned off the gravity from the galaxy, it would take even longer to notice.
It is true that there is a certain circularity to common definitions of 'inertial frame'. Newton's laws only apply in an inertial frame, and an 'inertial frame' is defined as one in which Newton's laws apply. (Constant straight-line motion in the absence of forces is just Newton's first law.) You are not the first person to notice.
It also turns out that compatibility with Newton's first law is not enough to guarantee compatibility with Newton's other two laws, although most physics textbooks will say so. The definition of 'inertial reference frame' is surprisingly subtle. (See here and here for more discussion.) A somewhat better definition (that I got from those links) is that inertial reference frames are those in which inertia is homogenous and isotropic (i.e. symmetric under translation and rotation). But the deeper you get into this subject, the more you realise everything is built on quicksand. If we start asking questions like how we define "straight line", "distance", "time", how do you define your rulers and clocks and protractors, and make sure they're all reporting the same thing, and we soon get into the foundational issues that lead on to general relativity.
When learning physics, it's better to start with the position that there are these sets of coordinates where Newton's laws apply, by means of which we can make reasonably accurate and practically useful predictions, and don't worry too much about where they come from, why they exist, or exactly how we can define them without circularity. You're perfectly right: there's something hinky here. Well done! But it's not easy to give an explanation suitable for a beginner. When you come to general relativity, you will study those foundations in more detail.
As George Box famously once said: "All models are wrong, but some are useful." The 'laws of physics' are models, and therefore should always be treated with a degree of scepticism. Much of the utility of physics is about learning to apply it in practical situations, so a lot of it is not particularly rigorous in the way it is taught. You will need to learn to accept that. But don't lose your curiosity about such issues, because they are a pathway into the most interesting and beautiful parts of the subject.

I concur that the mathpages website by Kevin Brown is a great resource. About the remark: "It is true that there is a certain circularity to common definitions of 'inertial frame'." That issue is discussed (briefly, but profoundly) in Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, available on archive.org: Section 12.3 Galilean coordinate systems The earlier discussion of the Lorentz force that is referenced section 3.1


Now my questions are why is Earth an approximate inertial reference frame for bodies on its surface? I do not find the explanation "Coriolis Force and Centrifugal forces have negligible effect over short distances " A convincing explanation.

It all depends how accurately you are measuring.
Say you shoot a pool ball across the table and measure where it stops using a meter-stick. You are not going to see any deviation from straight line motion to within the precision limits of the meter stick (say, 1 mm marks on its scale). If you were to measure with an interferometer with 1 nm precision, possibly you would actually see a deviation caused by the coriolis force (but I haven't done the math to check).
The Earth's surface is an approximate inertial frame...right up until you measure accuratelyl enough to detect the errors in that approximation.

suppose a satellite is being sent from here to Mars, Thus when it escapes earth's atmosphere, our "approximate inertial reference frame" should not work, and so What is the frame of reference is used for this scenario.

I am not a rocket engineer, but I'd guess you use the rest frame of the barycenter of the solar system.

most of the time the answers to my query is that an inertial reference frame is one which is not accelerating (Which is a meaningless statements as it violates the fact that there is no privileged observer in space and it is not accelerating to which frame?)

Observers in any inertial frame will agree about which objects are accelerating and which aren't. There isn't a privileged inertial frame that can detect accelerations that appear as non-acceleration in another inertial frame. That doesn't mean that accelerating frames are equivalent to inertial frames.
Also even if we are observing from an accelerating frame, we can still reason about what we would have seen if we did an observation from an inertial frame. It just takes knowledge of what acceleration we are experiencing and some math to account for it. When proper metrologists are doing precision measurements, they'll account for the coriolis force if necessary, along with other effects that are approximated to zero in everyday measurements, like the non-unity index of refraction of air, the non-zero time dilation from being in the Earth's gravity well, etc.


... but most of the time the answers to my query is that an inertial
reference frame is one which is not accelerating (Which is a
meaningless statements as it violates the fact that there is no
privileged observer in space and it is not accelerating to which
frame?)

It is easy to determine whether or not you are in an inertial reference frame or not. You do not need a second inertial reference frame as unlike constant linear motion, acceleration is in fact absolute. Simply attach a small mass to a spring and see if the spring is stretched and by how much. On the surface of the Earth, it is easy to see you are not in an inertial reference frame because the spring would be stretched in the downward direction due to gravity. This spring setup is basically an accelerometer and measures proper acceleration. An inertial reference frame is one where the observer does not measure any proper acceleration. An astronaut in a space station is in something very close to an inertial reference frame because in orbit they are in free fall.
Back on Earth, we can in principle measure forces like the Coriolis force acting on us, by measuring the difference between the alignment of our downward pointing spring and true vertical but this would be very difficult in practice as the device is not that sensitive to rotation. The best way to measure rotational forces is with a gyroscope or Foucault pendulum. These devices can detect the daily rotation of the Earth. Again, an inertial reference frame is one in which no proper forces (linear or rotational) are detected and the surface of the Earth definitely does not qualify.
However, you have to consider the context. If for example we are trying to measure or predict the acceleration of a car when a horizontal force is applied, the vertical force due to gravity becomes largely irrelevant (except for frictional forces between the car the road which is a fairly small factor) and the Coriolis force would be such a small factor it can be considered negligible in this example. The Coriolis force becomes more significant for measurement over longer distances. For example there is one sniper gum that takes Coriolis force into account in its targeting software, because it can make a small difference over a kilometer or so and sniper rifles are all about accuracy. Demonstrations of being able to opposite rotation of water in a bathroom sink a few yards either side of the Equator are scams set up to trick tourists and it has been shown that some of these so called demonstrations were not even exactly on the Equator. Look on YouTube for some of these demonstrations and observe the various tricks used to introduce an artificial swirl to the water.
In the context of trying to measure the difference effects of Special or General Relativity the inertiality of the reference frame becomes more important because the difference between the Newtonian prediction and the relativistic prediction is small because the Earths gravitational filed is relatively week as far as gravitational time dilation and length contraction are concerned. For most practical purposes, the difference is negligible, except for some special case like the clocks on GPS satellites that have to be highly accurate.
